# More idiomatic pattern in clojure than using instance? to dispatch on type

Tags: clojure, polymorphism

I have the following pattern that I am trying to implement:  I have an AST and 2 Generators, one for C# and one for VB.  A generator takes the provided AST as input and generates source code in the selected language.  First I define an abstraction for a generator:

```
(defprotocol Generator
  (generate-code [this ast]))
```

Then I give an implementation, one for C# and one for VB (I will just give the C# implementation because the VB one is almost exactly the same):

```
(defn ^:private gen-csharp-class [ast]
  (str "class " (:id ast) " {  }"))

(defn ^:private gen-csharp [ast]
  (cond
    (instance? AstClass ast) (gen-csharp-class ast)))

(defrecord AGenerator []
  Generator
  (generate-code [this ast] (gen-csharp ast)))
```

I don't like the use of `instance?` in the `gen-csharp` function.  Is there a more idiomatic way of writing this type of dispatch in Clojure?

Comment: please note, you can use `(defn- gen-csharp ...)` instead of `(defn ^:private gen-csharp ...)`

Comment: thanks @erdos, I prefer using `^:private` for consistency because there is no `def-` together with `defn-`, and historically `defn-` was added for convenience before `^:private` was so easy to write :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could reverse the abstraction:

```clj
(defprotocol CodeGenerator
  (generate-class [this ast])
  ;; + other generator methods
  )

(defrecord VBGenerator []
  CodeGenerator
  (generate-class [this ast] (gn-vb-class ast)))

(defrecord CSharpGenerator []
  CodeGenerator
  (generate-class [this ast] (gn-chsharp-class ast)))
```

and then write the `instance?` calls only once:

```clj
(defn gen-code [generator ast]
  (cond (instance? AstClass ast) (generate-class generator ast)
         ;; + other generator cases...
         ))
```

or you could use multimethods on the second argument for gen-class. Each multimethod definition would call the correct method from `CodeGenerator`:

```clj
(defmulti gen-class (fn [_ ast] (type ast)))

(defmethod gen-class AstClass [generator ast]
  (generate-class generator ast))
```

Comment: Condp (https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/condp) may be useful too, there is an example with instance?

Comment: Thanks @erdos.  I will have a look at all your suggestions and see which one works best for me.

Comment: Thanks @Rulle, I checked out condp.  I will definitely start using it more :)

Comment: @erdos, is there no other way to get rid of using `instance?` completely?

Comment: Marking this as the answer because this is what I chose to implement.  But the alternative about just using multimethods also looks great to me :)

Answer (score 2):

Alternatively, you can also use exclusively multimethods without protocols.

```clj
(defmulti gen-code (fn [language ast] [language (type ast)]))
```

Here the first parameter will be a keyword denoting the target language, however, you could use a type as well.

```clj
;; csharp definitions
(defmethod gen-code [:csharp AstClass] [_ ast]
  (gen-chsharp-class ast))

;; vb definitions
(defmethod gen-code [:vb AstClass] [_ ast]
  (gen-vb-class vb))

(defmethod gen-code [:vb AstNumber] [_ ast]
  ...)
...
```

then call gen-code with a node:

```clj
(gen-code :vb (new AstClass ...))
```